# DBeaver cannot connect PostgreSQL due to driver error

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, dbeaver

I am getting following error when I try to connect to PostgreSQL database on a Docker container during downloading and installing phase of PostgreSQL drivers:

***Driver file download failed. Do you want to retry? 

Reason: Maven artifact 'maven:/net.postgis:postgis-jdbc:RELEASE' not found***

On the other hand, when I run DBeaver via command line as admin, I can connect to the database. But not want to run DBeaver on terminal and want to fix that problem. I tried to add drivers as jar file but it does not fix the problem. So, how can I fix this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXX6B.png)

Comment: this doesn't look like docker related. especially judging from the image you attached. looks more like maven related. however you should add more details about your actual setup (dockerfile, commands, etc)

Comment: If it does not seem to be Docker related, then there may not be need to add Docker details. Instead, I think it is related to PostgreSQL drivers that could not been installed. Any idea?

Comment: Would be helpful to clarify this question a bit.  For example:  OP wrote: "I tried to add drivers as jar file".  
What was the name of the jar file added?  Where (what URL) did you get that file from?  Exactly where did you place that file?  Got a link to instructions that you followed to add jar file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.